# how can i expect ssh and run shell command?

Tags: shell, expect

**i want to mkdir at remote machine, but i dont know if the dir exists, how can i do this?**

i use `spawn ssh username@ip bash -c [ -d $dest_file ] && echo ok || mkdir -p $dest_file`

and returns

```
    while executing
"-d $dest_file "
    invoked from within
"[ -d $dest_file ] && echo ok || mkdir -p $dest_file"
    (file "mkdir.exp" line 22)
```

*i cant use ssh-key because my ip is dynamic*

Comment: Why not just run `ssh username@ip mkdir -p $dest_file`? That will create the directory if it doesn't exist, and will otherwise do nothing.

Comment: that works but i just want to know why `-d` doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

First, you probably don't need `bash -c` because `ssh` is already executing the command with your remote shell.

Secondly, you're not sufficiently quoting your ssh arguments. You're writing an expect script, which uses the [tcl](https://www.tcl.tk/about/language.html) programming language, and `[` is a special character that will attempt to evaluate its contents as a tcl command and return the output (read more [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl5.html)). For this to work properly, you would need to escape the opening `[` to get tcl to interpret it literally:

```
spawn ssh localhost \[ -d $dest_file ] && echo ok || mkdir -p $dest_file
```

This seems to work correctly on my system, but as I indicate in a comment it would be much easier to drop all the conditionals and just run:

```
spawn ssh localhost mkdir -p $dest_file
```

This accomplishes the same thing and doesn't run afoul of any quoting issues.